# Yii2 Gridview Custome column not display sort

Tags: yii2

I custome Gridview Column so sort not display

```
  [
                                'attribute' => 'name',
                                'format' => 'raw',
                                'header' => $type == 1 ? 'Tên khách hàng' : 'Tên liên hệ',
                                'value' => function ($model) {
                                    return Html::a($model->name, ['update', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'alink']);
                                },
                            ],
```

and sort not display

[image]

So  how customer header and add sort?

Comment: Don't add answers to act as comments.

Answer (score -1):

i comment attribute header so it work.

Answer (score -1):

i change header by label attribute so it work perfect.